# ProfileCredentialsProvider with Amazon SES and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ses

I want to Send an Email with Amazon SES and SpringBoot, I have this config file:

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Bean
    public AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService() {

        return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("ses-smtp-user.2024321-167419"))
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_2)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("myMailSender")
    public MailSender mailSender(
            AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService) {
        return new SimpleEmailServiceMailSender(amazonSimpleEmailService);
    }
}
```

using the field IAM User name from the credentials:

[image]

but I have this error when starting the app:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No AWS profile named 'ses-smtp-user.20211221-172419'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you pass to `ProfileCredentialsProvider()` is a local profile name, that should be a name present in your local `.aws/credentials` file. You're trying to pass it an IAM user name, which is a totally different thing.

First, I suggest you read [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html).

Second, I suggest you use environment variables instead of hard-coding any sort of credential settings in your code. You can either set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable, or set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables, and then your code would look like this:

```
return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_2)
                .build();
```

And in addition to being cleaner and simpler code, it will also automatically use the environment's assigned IAM role when running on EC2, ECS, Lambda, etc..